# Ember-CLI - Multiple Dynamic Segments doesn't render the right template

Tags: templates, dynamic, ember.js, ember-cli

Right now I am trying to set up nested routes that are dynamic segments. Such as /shop/:category/:item. Currently the router is set up as this:

*In router.js:*

```
Router.map(function() {
this.resource('shop', { path: '/shop' }, function(){
    this.resource('products.index', { path: '/:category' }, function(){
        this.route('product', { path: ':item' } );
});
```

If you are wondering why I have products.index, I had to put the ".index" at the end for it to pull the params from the URL. If I took out the index, I wouldn't be able to pull the dynamic segment from the URL in the route.

---

My file structure is as follows (only listing relevant files):

- controllers

  - products

    - index

      - product.js
    - index.js
- routes

  - products

    - index

      - product.js
    - index.js
- templates

  - products

    - index

      - product.hbs
    - index.hbs
    - product.hbs

I put product.hbs template both on the inside of a index folder as well as outside. I also tried putting "templateName", "viewName", "renderTemplate: function(){ this.render('products/index/product') }" in the route, nothing seems to work.

It always resolves to the products template page, never to the product page. I turned the ember log resolver on, and it says:

[✓] template:products/index

[✓] template:products/index

[✓] template:products/index

[✓] template:products/product

[✓] template:products/product

[✓] template:products/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

[ ] view:products/index/product

Anyone have any idea on what is causing this? Template for product is very simple, just a "TEST" in hbs.

Comment: Did you figure out this one? I have the same problem.

Comment: Whoops, sorry forgot to respond to this. So unfortunately I couldn't solve it using this specific technique so I had to do a workaround. I just ended up creating a whole new route all-together instead of nested resources.

So I did

`this.route('product', { path: '/shop/:category/:item' });`

in it's own separate line (not nested under a resource).